# Сигнатуры методов HashMap

Tags: java, generics, java-hashmap, hashmap

Почему метод `put` принимает на вход `key` параметр типа `K`:

```
public V put(K key, V value)
```

а метод `get` принимает на вход `key` параметр типа `Object`?

```
public V get(Object key)
```

Я пробовала в своей упрощённой реализации `HashMap` использовать методы

```
public V get(K key) 
public V put(K key, V value)
```

и это работает, точно так же, как работает и

```
public V get(Object  key) 
public V put(Object  key, Object value)
```

Насколько я понимаю, метод `put` должен принимать именно `K key` и `V value`, потому что в теле этого метода вызывается метод

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex)
```

и без явного приведения типов (`addEntry(hash, (K) key, (V) value, i);`) вызов этого метода вызвал бы ошибку компиляции, если бы `key` и `value` были бы типа `Object`. Но почему метод  `get` принимает на вход `key` параметр типа `Object`, а не `K`? Ведь это же как-то некрасиво, что ли (разный стиль)... и в этом должен быть, наверное, какой-то особый смысл.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Оргиниал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic)

Всё дело в том, что спецификация `Map` не требует того, чтобы все ключи имели одинаковый тип. Она лишь требует корректного поведения метода `equals` (и `hashCode` для `HashMap`) для объектов, которые используются в качестве ключей.

Конечно реализация метода `equals` обычно требует, чтобы совпадали, в том числе, классы сравниваемых объектов. Но есть случаи, где имеется другое поведение. К примеру при сравнении реализаций `java.util.List` (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList` и т.д.) требуется лишь, чтобы было эквивалентно именно содержимое этих списков. По указанной причине вы можете объявить переменную с типом `Map<ArrayList, String>` при этом в метод `get` передавать переменную типа `LinkedList` и это будет вполне рабочий вариант.

Если же задаваться вопросом зачем объявлять `Map<ArrayList, String>` вместо `Map<List, String>`, то я могу привести, хоть и узконаправленный, но всё же пример. Представьте, что ваша переменная с типом `Map<ArrayList, String>` периодически сериализуется, и вам очень важно быстродействие указанной сериализации. Поэтому вы требуете явно, чтобы записываемые ключи был именно указанного типа (я сейчас не буду говорить о реальной скорости сериализации `ArrayList`). А при поиске объекта-значения в метод `get` вы можете передавать аргумент любого типа, к примеру тот же `LinkedList`, что немного упростит вам жизнь.

P.S. На эту тему можно конечно подискутировать, но таковы реалии Java. Вполне возможно, что это недостаток проектирования. И ссылаясь на [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105812/5506820) могу сказать, что пытались сделать нечто подобное, но возникли некоторые трудности, и от этой идеи отказались.

Comment: Да, в этом видео, на которое есть ссылка в приведённом Вами ответе (втором) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDN_EYUvUq0, на 6-ой минуте точный ответ на мой вопрос)) Т.е., это не случайность, так именно было задумано: чтобы добавлять можно было только определённого типа данные, а для get() и remove() ключи могли бы быть любого типа (типа это не баг, это ради безопасности типов (type safety)). Спасибо большое за наводку и за прекрасный ответ! :)